# Python: ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures for parallelization

Tags: python, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I'm using `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` to parallelize my python code a snippet of which I've shown below.

```
import iris
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

if interpolate_bool:
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as exe:
       # submit tasks to load and save files
       _ = [exe.submit(interpolateCubes, item) for item in list(cube_dict.items())]
```

However this takes a long time to finish although the code does parallelize the process. For example, if my `cube_dict` has 60 items, it runs very fast for the first 58 items and then it almost dies or just hangs for the last 2 items.